What is the origin of robot sounds from early 70's TV shows like “Kolchak: The Night Stalker?”
Has anyone heard or remember hearing the creepy robot sound from the TV show "Kolchak: The Night Stalker" the episode called "Mr. R.I.N.G." (Episode 12)?
A beeping, twanging, whirring noise that was also on a Night Gallery episode and perhaps other science fiction TV shows from the 1960s.
I think it is an awesome sound effect and is quite scary sounding (to me).
I'm wondering who created that sound effect and what was used to create it?
Example in the episode at about 4:10 in:




Given that synthesizers were new tech in the very late 1960s, it's likely this was made by tape cutting -- editing recorded sounds together, as was done for a number of other "unearthly" sounds from that era.  Can't say for certain, though.

I've added a video link.  Please provide the start time for the sounds in question.

IMDB has a single sound credit for this episode: John K. Kean.

I believe some examples of the sounds in question are at timestamps 4:08, 4:30 and 46:20.  I'm sure there are some more in the middle of the episodes but I found those ones quickly

If you mean the warbling sound, it's a sheet of thin metal that's flexed close to a microphone or "played" using a bow from a violin or similar string instrument.
Similar in principle to a wobble board.
It's often recorded and either speed up or slowed down to create unearthly effects.
The mechanical grinding/ratcheting sound could an old rotary telephone or teletype machine. Both were commonly used to make "computer noises" during that period.
You can often see these effects in play on the Behind the Scenes shots for shows like Star Trek.

I'm pretty sure some of those noises are theremins, but it'd be hard to tell which is which after a few rounds of distortion and tape effects.

That's also a possibility, but I can defiantly hear a Wobble board type effect and a rotary telephone dial in there.
